# Link format as a preview

Tags: 7, entities, navigation

I'm asking if it exists a drupal module that let you make a preview of a link like the Facebook do.

In another way a display format which it gives a preview.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking for recommendations or suggestions on books, tools, modules, themes, distributions, tutorials, or other off-site resources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is one more similar module called [External Link Preview](https://www.drupal.org/project/external_link_preview)

> This module allows users to preview all the external links that are added into any text area field by fetching their metatags - title, description and image.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it's a new module, i will test it and tell you

Answer (score 5):

You can also try the [Opengraph Filter](http://drupal.org/project/opengraph_filter) which sorts of acts like Facebook's link preview. I haven't tried on link fields but it does work on a text body. Pretty neat actually :)

Answer (score 2):

[WebSnapr Preview Bubble](http://drupal.org/project/websnapr) module display screenshot of target page in popup.

Comment: Is that a paid service ?

Comment: thank you but it seems that module is used as service,

Comment: This module uses free Websnapr service (http://www.websnapr.com/free_services/) "Websnapr's basic services are completely free of charge. We provide 100,000 snapshot impressions for our free users per month."