# How to create a url/link preview?

Tags: 7, uri, navigation, entities

I'm managing a content sharing site built on drupal 7 and I would like to let users submit links as content.

Is there a simple way of creating a thumbnail / preview of the link (like on facebook)?

Answer (score 2):

I think [Opengraph Filter](https://drupal.org/project/opengraph_filter) is a better solution than [Facebook-Style Micropublisher](https://drupal.org/project/fbsmp) since FBSMP relies on Statuses module and both modules are not very stable yet and also they serve for a more specific purpose. Opengraph Filter does only that what you need.

Comment: Looks like this is a better solution.

Comment: True, and has been proved before http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/50615/link-format-as-a-preview

Answer (score 1):

This module might help

[Facebook-style Micropublisher](https://drupal.org/project/fbsmp)

> This module lets users publish content (links, images, videos and
>   documents) in a stream
>
> **Features**
>
> - Attaches content using AHAH which keeps everything smooth.
> - Ability to re-share/re-post attachments (links, images, etc).
> - API to allow users to share content (URL) from other sites on your website (similar to Google Bookmarks, Digg, Reddit links). More...
> - Publish links, photos, videos, documents (ppt, doc, pptx, odt, etc)    out of the box.
> - Extensible to publish any kind of content.
> - Integration with Activity 2, Twitter, Rules, Heartbeat,    Triggers/Actions, Input Filters, Views, ImageCache, Token,
>     Application Toolbar(Appbar), Emvideo, Emaudio, Userpoints (through
>     Rules), SlideShare.net API and more.
> - Extensive developer API (including hooks) and theming methods.    More...

Comment: Do you think this module is what was asked for and will serve the purpose?..As far as I know, this module is meant for attaching contents to FBSS and has a dependency on it. And here the question poster wants to have similar functionality for field added to content type. Though maybe the code fbsmp uses can be used.:)